# Restricting access to some url by groups(in urls.py, not with user_passes_test)

Tags: django, django-urls

For example, I have a group `manager`. I need to restrict access to     `url(r'^manager/', include('manager.urls')),` only for `Manager` and `Admin` groups. I saw this case in some post here, but can't find it. I remember that this access is restricted in `urls.py` not in `views.py`

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to achieve that is to create a middleware that would check the subset urls permissions.

Here is the example that basically requires user to login, but you can extend it with manager permission check - https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1220/

Less known approach is to replace `url(...)` with custom subclass of RegexURLResolver, that returns callable decorated with permission check.

For the reference see the -  [https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/urls/**init**.py#L70](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/urls/__init__.py#L70) and https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/urlresolvers.py#L246